# question on timedelta objec in for loop (python)

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have a TimeDelta object (say `T`) that has the output

```
Timedelta('0 days 10:30:05.25')
```

And I am concatenating its entries into a variable

```
var = str(T._h) + str(':') + str(T._m)
```

that produces the desired output: `'10:30'`

However, when I try to run the above within a for loop with changing `T` at each iteration, the output for var is `'0:0'`. I do get the desired output if I execute the quantity on the RHS of `var` at some iteration using a breakpoint. It seems that the for loop isn't allowing for saving this quantity into `var`? I had put a time-sleep amount prior but this didn't help.

Would appreciate any help on this.
Below is a sample example where a `t_str` at end of run will produce '0:0' while with a breakpoint, the correct answer will result.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd 

T = pd.to_timedelta('10.55hours')

for ii in range(0, 3):

    T = T + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=50)

    var = str(T._h) + str(':') + str(T._m)

    print(var)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: @Prune edited above with a mwe.

Comment: Not quite: your code produces no results.

Comment: Be careful with your example, however: if you `print(T)` anywhere after the update, you evaluate the outstanding object, and again get the expected output, rathe than the bug.  I'm sorry that I don't know why this happens.

Comment: @Prune Yes, I don't get the expected output after each update on `var` within the loop. I get '0:0' on Python 2.7

Comment: Why are you using the underscored attributes (e.g. `._h`) and not the normal ones like e.g. `.hour`?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem and will produce desired output

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

T = pd.to_timedelta('10.55hours')

for ii in range(0, 3):
    T = T + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=50)
    print(T)
    var = "%d:%d:%d.%d" % (T._h, T._m, T._s, T._ms)
    print(var)
    # output : 10:33:0.150
```

Comment: thank you - can you also tell me how I can include for seconds and milliseconds? e.g., if the Timedelta looked like `10:33:30.2500`

Comment: thank you but that isn't working for me ... i am getting `0:0:0.0` :(